# jQuery Close dropdown menu open when another menu is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have this code:
http://jsfiddle.net/a9GUX/

Example, when the menu "one" is open, and the person clicks on the menu "four", the menu one closes automatically. I've done some tests but some do nothing and others open all / close all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to work fine in my browsers. Menu "One" stays open even though I am opening and closing "four" repeatedly. What browser are you using?

Comment: that's the problem :P
zoltan solved this.
http://jsfiddle.net/a9GUX/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line

```
$(this).siblings('li').children('ul,p').slideUp('slow');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/a9GUX/1/)

Comment: it's possible to make the menu opened when the person entering the page?
For example:
If the person chose the menu 'one 1', when the page is opened, the dropdown 'One' remains open.
I'm not sure I was clear ...
Thank you.

Comment: where does the user choose menu "one 1" if he isn't on the page yet?

Comment: in this case the dropdown works on all pages, and 'one' is just to open the submenus ... if I'm on page zero, I can see the submenus of the page 'one'. now, when the person goes to the page 'one 1' the menu is closed ... I would like it to remain open ...  do you understand? xD

Comment: All I can think of is using cookies.. You can set the `window.location.hash` to the current menu item name, but it will be lost if you open a new page.

Comment: I managed to add a class with "display: block! important," to the menu that would have to stay open, but it makes it not to close more later (when I open another).
http://jsfiddle.net/a9GUX/2/